# Let $φ$ be the density of the $χ^2(n)$ distribution. Find the point at which $φ$ has its maximum.

Tags: statistics, chi-squared

Let φ be the density of the $χ^2(n)$ distribution. Find the point at which $φ$ has its maximum.

I can't really find a way to solve this question! Any help is welcome.

EDIT: I am given this one hint, which I don't understand where it could be used
(the algebra can be simplified by appropriate use of logarithms)

Comment: $\phi'(x)=0$ ????

Comment: Given the hint, I don't think it is that simple

Comment: @AnishDarnal : The hint about logarithms was there for a reason, and you're ignoring it. The point is that since the logarithm function is increasing, the density function and its logarithm both reach their maximum values at the same point. So work with the logarithm of the density function rather than with the density directly because it's simpler. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, Let's deal with the hint about logarithms.

The density of the chi-square distribution with $n$ degrees of freedom is
$$
f(x) = \text{constant} \cdot x^{(n/2)-1} e^{-x/2}.
$$
So you have
$$
\log f(x) =\text{constant} + \left( \frac n 2 - 1\right) \log x - \frac x 2.
$$
Since $\log$ is an increasing function, $f$ and $\log\circ f$ both reach their maximum values at the same point.

So you have
$$
\frac d {dx} \log f(x) = \left( \frac n 2 -1 \right) \frac 1 x - \frac 1 2.
$$
This should be positive if $0<x<\text{something}$ and negative if $x$ is larger than that.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot!